# ClientException "failed to parse header value" when using Googleapis_auth package with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, flutter-web

I'm trying to develop a flutter (web) application which needs to invoke access restricted http triggered cloud functions.

Therefore I have created a service account in my google cloud console and followed the example on how to retrieve an authenticated http client as an autonomous application of the googleapis_auth package (https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_auth).

```
final accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''{ "private_key_id": "****", "private_key": "****", "client_email": "****.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "client_id": "****", "type": "service_account" }'''); 
var scopes = [CloudfunctionsApi.CloudPlatformScope]; 
AuthClient client = await clientViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes);
```

This seems to work fine. But when I try to use the received client to make a post request to my cloud function, I get a ClientException ("failed to parse header value").

```
http.Response resp = await client.post( CloudFunctiontriggerURL, body: {'data': userId});
```

As I understand the examples, this should work fine without specifying any headers manually in the POST function call. Correct?
However, even if I specify the header manually, I get this error.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are getting `401 Unauthorized: "Failed to parse header value"` exception.

In order to invoke a restricted http **Cloud Functions**, the service account need the `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` permission which can be granted with the role `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`. Please confirm this.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles

Comment: thanks for your response. But yes I have granted the "Cloud Functions-Invoker" role to the used service account.

Comment: please see edit. I hope it helps and it is what you meant.

Comment: No, this wasn't. I mean't the full error that is alongside `Failed to parse header value`

Comment: Okay sorry. Could you tell me how to retrieve the required information? I have never needed this before and therefore I am still quite inexperienced with this.

Comment: I would suggest you to contact the Google Cloud Platform Support, with the project id and cloud function name that you need help with. https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: So I've talked to one of your collegues. On GCP side, it all seems to be configured correctly. Issue should be within flutter code.